# Prove that sum of the square of Fibonacci numbers from 1 to n is equal to the nth Fibonacci number multiplied by the n+1 th Fibonacci Number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have a special definition for the Fibonacci numbers in this case. Fibonacci numbers are defined by $f_1 = 1$, $f_2 = 2$, and  $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1}+f_n$ for all $n$ in natural numbers. Prove that for all natural numbers $n$:

$1+f_1^2+f_2^2+\ldots+f_n^2=f_nf_{n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cool visual depiction of this result:

[image]
Some would even call this a 'Proof by Picture', but you probably want to use a more formal method to prove this, possibly inspired by this picture. I suggest you use induction.

Answer (score 1):

So the induction step will need to prove:

If we assume $f_1^2 + f_2^2+.....+ f_n^2 = f_nf_{n+1}$

we need to prove

$[f_nf_{n+1}] + f_{n+1}^2 = f_{n+1}f_{n+2}$.

As $f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + f_n$ that should be straight forward.

Just do it.